# Is it necessary to close Scanner when there is no stream underlying?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Directly from this Scanner [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29):

```
String input = "1 fish 2 fish red fish blue fish";
     Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s*fish\\s*");
     System.out.println(s.nextInt());
     System.out.println(s.nextInt());
     System.out.println(s.next());
     System.out.println(s.next());
     s.close();
```

Comment: It is a good practice to always close your ressources onces you are done with them or the compiler will complain and mumble errors about memory leaks.

Answer (score 5):

> First we make our habits; then our habits make us.

I'd say close the stream, because ingraining a habit like closing resources in `finally` blocks make sense.

Answer (score 5):

Even though a scanner is not a stream, you need to **close** it to indicate that you're done with its underlying stream [[1]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html). IDEs like Eclipse will often issue a warning that you have a "Resource leak: 'scanner' is never closed".

**Note:** **don't close** a Scanner that's tied to **System.in**! Since the System.in object is opened by the JVM, you should leave it to the JVM to close it [[2]](https://coderanch.com/wiki/678613/Don-close-Scanner-tied-System).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, but it's best to close it anyway in case you change your code to use a stream. It's also a good habit, one that you really want to get into.

Answer (score 1):

There will be no resource leak if we dont close `Scanner` of String. Internally `new Scanner(String)` creates a `StringReader` as underlying source, when we close `Scanner` it closes `StringReader` which makes no effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the **Scanner** to be marked as closed (so that all subsequent operations on the object will fail immediately), then you must call **Scanner.close()**.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a good idea of using `scanner.close()`;
I say this because it will prevent resource leaks and if you make this into a habit then it will be very beneficial to you.