# Insertion in Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, insertion

I am writing a code to insert an element in an array. The expected output is that the element gets inserted in the input index by shifting the elements on the right side.
I am trying to print the elements after first iteration using the nested j loop and it is giving me a NoSuchException error.
To understand it better by wanting to see the list where Java errors are explained using code such as 'Scanner.java:937'.
Where can I find the list and where am I doing wrong in my code ?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        int A[] = new int[N + 2];
        for(int i = 1; i <= N + 2; i++){
            A[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int X = sc.nextInt();
        int Y = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i = 1; i <= N + 2; i++){
            if(i == X){
                for(int j = 1; j <= N + 2; j++){
                    A[j + 1] = A[j];
                }
                for(int j = 1; j <= N + 2; j++){
                    System.out.print(A[j]+ " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to print the elements after first iteration and want to see the list where java error are explained using code number.

Comment: Remember [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)!

Comment: Did I just notice that something was edited by @MorganFreeFarm ?

Comment: @Earth Yes, it was.

Comment: @Earth he changed the tags for you like [so](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77107065/revisions)(basically by removing PHP)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the statement that [you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77107065/insertion-in-array#comment135930875_77107133):

> Write a program to input N numbers array, a number X and a number Y
> from user and insert an element Y in it at specified position X. X is
> based on 1-based indexing Note: When an element is inserted at
> position X, all elements that were already present at position >= X,
> gets shifted to one position right, not replaced.

You can do this way:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Array size
        int N = input.nextInt();

        // Create the array
        int[] array = new int[N];

        // Loop
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            // Input each array element
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        // Position
        int X = input.nextInt();

        // Number to be inserted
        int Y = input.nextInt();

        // Check the position
        if (X >= 1 && X <= N + 1) {
            // New array with one extra element
            int[] resultArray = new int[N + 1];

            // Copy elements to the new array
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < N + 1; i++) {
                if (i == X - 1) {
                    // Insert Y at position X
                    resultArray[i] = Y; 
                } else {
                    resultArray[i] = array[j];
                    j++;
                }
            }

            // Print the array
            for (int num : resultArray) {
                System.out.print(num + " ");
            }
        } else {
            //TODO: Deal with the invalid position
        }
    }
}
```

But [you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77107065/insertion-in-array#comment135930831_77107133):

> The question says that X is based on 1-based indexing. What does that mean ?

Well, when you create an array like this:

```java
int[] array = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

You can say that the first number is `1`, but his index is actually `0`!

It means that:

```java
array[0] = 1
array[1] = 2
array[2] = 3
array[3] = 4
array[4] = 5
```

This is the `0-Based Indexing`, the indexing used in programs.

So, what is `1-Based Indexing`? It's the *""real life""* indexing. **It means that the item `1` must have the index `1`**.

You can see it in the code:

```java
if (i == X - 1) {
    // Insert Y at position X
    resultArray[i] = Y; 
}
```

I verify if `i == X - 1` because if the user input `1` it means that he wants to change the first index, **but in the code the first index is actually `0` and not `1`**.

Comment: `input.close()` -> Consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60632632/21252090) on closing Scanners that use `System.in`

Comment: @GrindingForReputation I let it in the code because in my opinion its a good practice in small examples. But anyway thank you for the recommendation, it is really relevant in bigger scopes.

Comment: Well makes sense and I do understand! The reason I pointed this out is because people (like me when I was a beginner) used to copy code off of Stack Overflow without completely understanding what the code/certain lines in the code do/does. This could later cause problems for whoever use `input.close()` and would be unsure on why/how this occurs as this isn't an error.

Comment: @Diego No, it's not 'good practice in small examples'. It's _bad_ practice. __Do not close any resource unless _you_ are the one responsible for it__. You are not responsible for `System.in` therefore you __must not__ close it.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Thank you for the information! I've removed it from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First here are a few places you are going wrong:

- you need to allocate a new array to hold the original values plus the inserted one.  Otherwise, you will either throw an exception as arrays do not grow dynamically as needed but must be copied.
- The following loop cascades the value at `A[j]` to the end of the array, overwriting previous values.

```
    for(int j = 1; j <= N + 2; j++ ){
              A[j + 1] = A[j];
    }
```

And as mentioned in the comments, using meaningful names helps document the code. (e.g. You defined `X` and `Y` but never used `Y` so it wasn't immediately clear what they were for).

Here is an alternative approach. I recommend using an initialized array to facilitate testing.  Prompting for array input can be done later when the code is working as expected.

```
int[] items = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int n = items.length;

int location = sc.nextInt();
int itemToInsert = sc.nextInt();

if (location >= items.length + 1 || location < 0) {
    System.out.println("Invalid location.");
} else {

    // copy up to the location point
    int[] newItems = new int[items.length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < location; i++) {
        newItems[i] = items[i];
    }
    // insert the new value
    newItems[location] = itemToInsert;

    // append the remaining values.
    for (int i = location; i < items.length; i++) {
        newItems[i + 1] = items[i];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newItems));
   
}
```

- First, there is nothing wrong with your approach once you get the indices et al, corrected.
- The above, imo, has the following advantages.

  - it is simpler and doesn't iterate more than the alternative.
  - it doesn't need to test for the insertion point.
  - and it caters to inserting `before` the `first element` and `after` the `last element`.  But that is an implementation decision.