# My code won't run, im not sure where the errors are, or if there are any

Tags: java

so ive been trying to run this code, but idk what im doing wrong cuz it won't run. Im like a beginner, beginner in coding. Pls help

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class sample{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);

        String userName = obj.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Employee name: " + userName);

        String dept = obj.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Department: " + dept);

        int userNo = obj.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Employee number: " + userNo);

        obj.close();
    }
}
```

edit: omg sorry!! i accidentally edited it in while making this question, this is the actual code and still it won't run

Comment: Your code starts by accepting input from the console (using `obj.nextLine()`). Are you entering anything into the console?

Comment: what does "does not run" mean? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: i did, when i coded this on my phone, i got an input mismatch exception at the nextInt(). I thought it was just some weird fluke cuz i was coding on a phone, so i tried it on my laptop, and when i hit run, it does not run?? idk how else to explain it, but it just won't run

Comment: `obj.close()` -> Consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945683/is-it-necessary-to-close-scanner-when-there-is-no-stream-underlying/60632632#60632632) on closing Scanners that use `System.in`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class sample{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);

        String userName = obj.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Employee name: " + userName);

        String dept = obj.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Department: " + dept);

        int userNo = obj.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Employee number: " + userNo);

        obj.close();
    }
}
```

IDK what you though "obj" was, but it wasn't a variable you declared.
It wasn't running because you were using a scanner that didn't exist.

Comment: hi! yeah this was my original code, im so sorry for the mix up but yeah it still won't run..

Answer (score 0):

So with this info from your comment -> *"i did, when i coded this on my phone, i got an input mismatch exception at the nextInt()."* The reason you get this error is because you tried to input a string value instead of an int value. Look below.

```
John
Employee name: John
Supervisor
Department: Supervisor
25
Employee number: 25
```

I inputted the following values if it isn't obvious enough -> John, Supervisor and 25. The program ran with no error

```
John
Employee name: John
Supervisor
Department: Supervisor
IV
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:947)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1602)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2267)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2221)
    at sample.main(sample.java:13)
```

And again I inputted the following values if it still isn't obvious enough -> John, Supervisor and IV.

IV is not an integer so I cannot input IV, instead I will have to use 4. **Any data value that is not an integer will give you this error**.

---

And **do not close the scanner**, or more generally **do not close input streams that you did not create**.

Comment: omg T-T lmao im so dumb, i got it, thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score -1):

You have declared the scanner object as obj1 but using obj in your code..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter employee name:");
        String userName = obj.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Employee name: " + userName);

        System.out.println("Enter department:");
        String dept = obj.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Department: " + dept);

        System.out.println("Enter employee no:");
        int userNo = obj.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Employee number: " + userNo);

        obj.close();
    }
}
```

Try this..

Answer (score -2):

you declared your scanner object as "obj1" but you are trying to "obj" instead
and when reading input from "username" and "dept", you should use obj1 instead of obj and you were read an integer input using obj.nextInt() but obj was not declared